# how to use a Twitter bootstrap plug in

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

So, I'm using twitter bootstrap for my website. I have made a navigation menu and one of the items should be a dropdown. I want this to happen when you hover over the item.
Twitter Boostrap does not support this. So I found a plug-in which should do it.

http://cameronspear.com/blog/twitter-bootstrap-dropdown-on-hover-plugin/

This^ is the one.
However.. For some reason, I don't understand where I need to put this code..

Sorry, I'm kind of new to this.

EDIT: Title

Comment: Just include it into your code either as a `script` tag in the `head`, or in a `script` tag in the `body`. It probably has to come *after* the `script` tag that loads the bootstrap js.

Answer (score 0):

Directly on the website you provided explains how to implement this plugin. After you include his plugin javascript all you need to do is:

The markup must be the same as it normally is with Bootstrap's dropdowns, and then to activate, you just add `data-hover="dropdown"` where you'd add `data-toggle="dropdown".`

This is explained near the bottom of his post, right above the comments. Hope this helps!

EDIT: Here is the code example off his website:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="1000" data-close-others="false">
        Account <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">My Account</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Change Email</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Change Password</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I don't know where I need to add this extra code

Comment: No problem! Simply create a new .js file and paste in his code off the website in to it. Then include the new .js file with his code in your <header> where you included your other .js files. Then where you create your navigation, make the changes as explained above or on his website. His website provides a full example of what exactly to include on the navigation.

Comment: You see.. The odd thing is, I did all that. But it just doesn't work. I made a new .js called dropdownonhover.js, I put it below all the bootstrap scripts. My HTML looks like this:

Comment: <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="1000" data-close-others="false">Restaurant<b class="caret"></b>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="restaurant.html">Restaurant</a></li>
                            <li><a href="../menu/MenuEN.pdf" target="_blank">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="../menu/Wijnkaart.pdf" target="_blank">Wine</a></li>
                       </ul>
                    </li>

Comment: Have you been clearing your browser cache? Every time you do any updates that involve javascript you need to clear your cache otherwise it will not update your changes.
If you are using chrome hit F12 to open Developer tools then click and hold on the browser refresh button to have a dropdown of options then click 'Empty Cache and Hard Reload'

Comment: Still doesn't work... I don't see what I'm doing wrong. Thanks for the top tough!